# Read and writing to multiple files concurrently?

Tags: multithreading

I've got a software application where it can have over a million objects in memory using all the cores of the machine. Each object has a unique ID and has it's own internal `StateObject` that needs to be persisted temporarily somewhere, any changes to the `StateObject` will result in overwriting previous `StateObject` with new updated data.

I was wondering if I should be reading & writing the state to a database or should I just create text files locally on the machine, each named with uniqueId of the object and each object will read and write a json String of `StateObject` to the file.

Which option will yield better performance?  database or to just writing to local file system? Should I write to multiple files with uniqueId or one file with multiple rows where the first column will be the unique id ? After doing some research I found that parallel read and writes are slower on HDD but is fast on SSD. So I guess I have to use SSD.

**Update**
The reason to write to disk is because there are too many `Objects`s (> 1Million) and having each `object`'s all their `StateObject`s in memory is going to be expensive so I would rather persist the `Object`'s internal `State` (`StateObject`) to disk if they are not being used. And guarantee of the writes is very important to process the next request by that object. If the write fails for some reason the `StateObject` will be built from a remote APIs before processing the next request which is more time consuming.

Comment: Use an in-memory cache like [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) that you can configure to have persistant state. Saves you having to roll your own file managment.

Comment: Will Redis be a good option if I only want to keep the `StateObject` in memory to process a request and as soon as the request is processed I would like to flush the new `StateObject` to disk ? The reason is because there are too many `StateObject`s (> 1Million) and having all their `StateObjects` in memory is going to be expensive.

Comment: Too generic. Define **database**. Hint - whatever you do with those files, you will end up using **a database** of a sort. Now, obviously, you should not be using any external, relational database - this would be a terrible performance drag. But something like in-memory no-sql database backed up by storage sounds like a good solution. Asking for a specific example of one, though, would be off topic.

Comment: Don't use a million files! Store multiple objects (let's say 100) in each file and use the OS capabilities (e.g. LockFile() on windows) to lock only part of a file and ensure trouble-free concurrency. Store your 10000 files in multiple folders, too many files in a single folder can have a negative performance impact.

Comment: Bascially you don't want to have the hassle of managing memory and writes to disk, there are many solutions that will do this for you (e.g. NoSQL or caches). You haven't stated how big you `StateObject` is and how much RAM you have available. 1 million objects isn't necessarilya lot of RAM. If its more RAM than one server can handle look at solutions that can cluster memory across muliple hosts (e.g. coherence). I agree that your question is too vague at present.

Comment: Thanks Guys, all your suggestions suggest that I use in-memory NoSQL datastore like Redis like what @Brad mentioned and after reading up on Redis .. I will do just that.. Thank you.